# Symplectic group over integers and finite fields

Tags: finite-groups, symplectic-group

For  $H=\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$  and a commutative ring $F$, the symplectic group $Sp(2n,F)$ is the set of all matrices $M\in F^{2n\times 2n}$ such that $MHM^T = H$. (Here, $M^T$ means the transposed matrix.)

My question is: for $\mathbb{F}_p$ a finite field of prime order, is $Sp(2n,\mathbb{F}_p) = Sp(2n,\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb F_p$, the reduction mod $p$ of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your tensor product notation between a group and a field.

Comment: I mean reduction of the coefficients mod p. Fixed.

Comment: The problem was not so much the notation (which is fine), but the fact that you define $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,R)$ as a group, rather than an $R$-scheme. I'm sure this is what you meant, but it isn't what you're writing.

Comment: @René: I see. And of course, the fact that it is a group does not matter for the question.

Comment: Are you asking whether ${\rm Sp}(2n, \mathbb{Z}) \to {\rm Sp}(2n, \mathbb{F}_p)$ is surjective?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Yes.

Comment: Reduction modulo $p$ of a group makes no sense, indeed. Thanks to Piotr who guess what you had in mind and didn't write...

Comment: Does it really suffice, when checking the behaviour of a scheme under base change, to check what happens on its potentially very small set of rational points?  That is, if $X_0$ is a scheme over $\mathbb Z$, $X_p$ is a scheme over $\mathbb F_p$, and we have a morphism of schemes $f : X_0 \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb F_p \to X_p$ such that $X_0(\mathbb Z) \to X_p(\mathbb F_p)$ is surjective, then does that imply that $f$ is an isomorphism of schemes?  For example, the order-6 group $\mathrm{Sp}(2, \mathbb F_2) \cong \mathrm S_3$ is accidentally generated by an order-2 and an order-3 element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:  $\operatorname{Sp}(2n, \mathbb F_p)$ is generated by its root subgroups.  Each root subgroup is cyclic, and generated by an element that lifts in an obvious way to $\operatorname{Sp}(2n, \mathbb Z)$.

More concretely, if I haven't messed up the calculations in your form (I'm used to a different one), then, writing $E_{i j}$ for the matrix that has a 1 in its $(i, j)$th entry and 0 elsewhere, we have that $\operatorname{Sp}(2n, \mathbb F_p)$ is generated by:

- $\{1 + t(E_{i j} - E_{(j + n)(i + n)}) : t \in \mathbb F_p\}$ (corresponding to the root $e_i - e_j$) for $1 \le i < j \le n$,
- $\{1 + t(E_{i(j + n)} + E_{j(i + n)}) : t \in \mathbb F_p\}$ (corresponding to the root $e_i + e_j$) for $1 \le i \ne j \le n$,
- $\{1 + t E_{i(i + n)} : t \in \mathbb F_p\}$ (corresponding to the root $2e_i$) for $1 \le i \le n$,
  and
- the transposes of the various groups above (corresponding to the negative roots).

The $e_i - e_j$ generators correspond to an elementary row operation in the upper left block, combined with its inverse transpose in the lower right block. The $e_i + e_j$ and $2e_i$ generators generate symmetric matrices in the upper right block.