# Symplectic group over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by its root subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, algebraic-k-theory, symplectic-group

This is a question about the answer in this other post: [Symplectic group over integers and finite fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230885/symplectic-group-over-integers-and-finite-fields/230889#230889?newreg=e4305c224d9e449b85edc359d5eba6ff).

<s>In general, for any ring $R$, the symplectic group $\text{Sp}(2n,R)$ is generated by its root subgroups and a maximal torus $T$.</s>

Why is $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ generated only by its root subgroups, where $p$ is a prime number?

A reference to a book that discusses this would already make me very happy, but I haven't been able to find one...

Comment: Because $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$ is simply-connected and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field. The standard reference is "Lectures on Chevalley groups" by R. Steinberg.

Comment: Also, the symplectic group over a commutative ring is usually not generated by its elementary subgroup and a maximal torus.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, @AndreiSmolensky! I have been looking at your reference, but I haven't been able to find it there either (I am quite new to this area of math...). Could you maybe recommend a certain chapter where I can find this result? Also, I am assuming that by "elementary subgroup" you mean the root subgroups. Is it true that my claim works for $R=\mathbb{Z}$? I mean that $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by its root subgroups and a maximal torus $T$. Thanks again and looking forward to your reply!

Comment: The elementary subgroup is by definition the subgroup generated by the root subgroups.
$\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by its root subgroups as well. The simplest way to see this is perhaps by means of the stable rank condition, see "Stability theorems for $K_1$, $K_2$ and related functors modeled on Chevalley groups" by M. Stein. It essentially shows an explicit way to decompose any symplectic matrix into a product of elementary root unipotents by reducing it to a matrix in $\operatorname{SL}_2$ and finishing it off with by Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Also, I now think that Steinberg notes is not the best source for this particular question (over fields), because he defines Chevalley groups as genetated by the root subgroups. R. Carter does the same in "Simple groups of Lie type", but also provides the identification with the classical groups.

Comment: Another good source for symplectic (and other classical) groups over rings is "The Classical groups and $K$-theory" by Hahn an O'Meara.

Answer (score 2):

I'll spell out Andrei Smolensky's [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401996/symplectic-group-over-mathbbz-p-mathbbz-is-generated-by-its-root-subgroup#comment1027673_401996) a bit (and remove this from the unanswered list).

(1) For any field $k$, the group $\operatorname{SL}_2(k)$ is generated by its elementary subgroups. In particular, you can see that the torus is generated by elementary subgroups because
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ a-a^2&1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1/a \\ 0&1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\ -1+a&1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ 0&1 \\ \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 1/a&0 \\ 0&a \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

(2) For each pair of roots $\pm \alpha$ of a reductive group $G$, we get a map from $\operatorname{SL}_2$ to $G$. In particular, the torus of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ maps to the one parameter subgroup in the torus of $G$ corresponding to $\pm \alpha^{\vee}$. So, if the co-roots span the co-weight lattice (which is equivalent to $G$ being simply connected), then the tori of these various $\operatorname{SL}_2$'s will generate the torus of $G$.

Concretely, the co-roots of the symplectic group are $\pm e_i \pm e_j$ and $\pm e_k$, inside the co-weight lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n = \bigoplus \mathbb Z e_i$, and it is clear that these span.

Comment: The title of the question is a bit different from its body, but, just to be clear, this is information only over a field, not over a ring, right?

Comment: Also, I think I might prefer to call what you've written down the co*character* lattice of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$ (or the co*root* lattice of type $\mathsf C_n$), since it is only of index $2$ in what I would call the co*weight* lattice, by which I mean the integral dual to the root lattice (which also contains $\tfrac1 2\sum e_i$).